# How I can use getPixel method on BitmapImage class?

Tags: windows-phone-7, bitmap, writeablebitmap

I mean I want to use get pixel method on wp7. I do not use Bitmap class.It is possible or I don't use it and I can use writeableBitmap instead of Bitmap. And when I use writeableBitmap class I can not use getPixel method.How I can use?

for ex:

```
WriteableBitmap image;
int a=image.GetPixel(i, j).G;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/), it has GetPixel and SetPixel method extensions you can use here!